# Remove Windows 8 OS from my laptop and install Linux

Tags: linux, windows-8

How can I remove Windows 8 completely and install Linux Peppermint on my laptop? I have tried accessing the bios, and this system has UEFI. When following the proper procedure, it ended up getting stuck in a Repair loop. I need to know the right procedure so that it does not happen again. I have already made backup recovery disks for this computer, but I really do not want Windows 8 at all. If someone could please help, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. I have been at this for quite some time now, and just was looking for confirmation as it would not complete the Peppermint install. I did not realize that the formatting choice would allow me to do so at the time of install. I will be back later with an update. I received a -1 for my question, so it will probably be removed as being not relevant.

Comment: @maxreport : It will be helpful if you post some details about the error you are getting.

Comment: Improve your post, with your error message, normal install steps should be enough to finish the proccess but we cant guess where are you getting stuck without the proper information. improve and  ill reverse my vote.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to change any BIOS settings.

1. Prepare a flash drive/CD with Peppermint Linux.
2. Start your computer and tap <kbd>F9</kbd> repeatedly until you get an option to boot from your flash drive or CD or Hard drive, and pick the appropriate one. (<kbd>F9</kbd> might not ALWAYS be the correct key for this, just try it and see.)
3. The Peppermint installer should start. Go through the steps, and when it asks how to partition the drives, tell it to `Use the whole disk`.
4. Finish the setup steps.
5. Reboot, and start using Peppermint!

Comment: The only change to the BIOS would be to change the boot order so that the CD drive or USB starts before the HDD. This way, you don't need to know what key to press for the boot options (mine is F8 btw)

Comment: @Cfinley But of course, if you use the F<whatever>-key, you don't have to change the BIOS settings, and change it back. I find the F<whatever>-key route to be much simpler.

Comment: @Cfinley Also, most BIOS start screens tell you which key to press to change the Boot order.

Comment: As do I. I was just pointing out another way to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Peppermint, just format the disk or partition that Windows is currently on. Formatting a disk/partition is the easiest way to remove an operating system.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).